# How do you inherit from template class when you need to inherit not from template?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

Sounds bad.. but having

```
template < int ArrayLength, typename SomeValueType > class SomeClass{
    SomeValueType SomeValue;
    SomeValueType SomeArray[ ArrayLength ];
    ...
};
```

how do you for example ceae a class that expands `SomeClass` that is `SomeClass < 20, int >`

is something like

`class  MyClass : SomeClass < 20, int > {...};` correct way?

Comment: you know that this is private inheritance by default? use class MaClass : public SomeClass<20,int>{...}; to have public inheritances.

Comment: If `MyClass` might be deleted via a `SomeClass*`, then you should also add a virtual destructor to `SomeClass` to ensure any additional MyClass-specific destruction steps are executed....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want private inheritance:

```
class MyClass : SomeClass < 20, int > //private by default!
{ 
    //...
};
```

If you want public inheritance:

```
class MyClass : public SomeClass < 20, int > 
{ 
    //...
};
```